# Get the month when click in the bar

Tags: jquery, flot

When I handle the click in some bar in the chart, I can get the Y axis value, but the X axis I want get the month, and nowadays I get a strange value.

```
$("#flot-dashboard-chart2").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {            
     if (item) {
          var dataPoint = item.series.data[item.dataIndex];          
          // dataPoint[0] - Return a strange value, a want the month
          // dataPoint[1] - Return the Y value (works fine)
     }
});
```

**My Chart**

```
 var options = {
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                tickSize: [1, "month"],
                tickLength: 0,
                axisLabel: "Date",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10,
                color: "#838383",                
                timeformat: "%b/%y"
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, with the following function.

```
    /* HANDLE CLICK IN BAR */
    $("#flot-dashboard-chart2").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {            
        if (item) {
            var dataPoint = item.series.data[item.dataIndex];                
            var month = GetMonth(item);               
        }
    });    

    /* GET THE MONTH IN X AXIS */
    function GetMonth(item)
    {        
        var content = "%x";
        var xPattern = /%x\.{0,1}(\d{0,})/;
        // change x from number to given label, if given
        if (typeof item.series.xaxis.ticks !== 'undefined') {

            var ticks = 'ticks';                       
            var tickIndex = item.dataIndex + item.seriesIndex;

            if (item.series.xaxis[ticks].length > tickIndex)
                content = content.replace(xPattern, item.series.xaxis[ticks][tickIndex+1].label);
        }

        // Return Nov/14 for example
        return content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the data and what you get, one can only guess, so here is my guess:

when you access dataPoint[0], you probably get a timestamp (number of milliseconds since 1st january 1970, something like this:  1404999276000).
In javascript, you can easily convert a timestamp to a date:

```
date = new Date(timestamp);
```

It returns something like this :

```
Thu Jul 10 2014 15:34:36 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
```

You can then extract the month with [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

```
date.getMonth()  // return 6 (july, january is 0)
```